# How updates in Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API are released

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API to communicate the Azure Active Directory . My code parses response received from API  and compares error message in some specific error scenarios . Recently I observed one my scenario was failing due to change in response message from the API. I am just curios how these changes are pushed by Microsoft . Are customers notified for these changes ? Are changes released region wise or customer wise ? My code is being used by mates in other geographic reason also , they have not reported any failure till now.

For Example. Previously Error message for expired password was "Forced Password Change"  now message is "Password is expired"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are customers notified for changes ?**

Once the service update is applied by Microsoft you will receive a notification if the update was successful or if it was not able to be applied. When any maintenance plan to happen all the partners and user receives notification about that.  You could find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/fin-and-ops/get-started/one-version#what-happens-when-the-service-update-is-complete)

**Are changes released region wise or customer wise ?**

Usually changes made on regionally. But sometimes data center wise also. But its very rare pointing to specific customer. Some small enhancement take place (Like yours) that's impact less on application and partner as well. In that case you may not receive any notification for that. Other then you would definitely receive mail concerning the issue. For more details you could take look on [service life cycle policy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17140/lifecycle-faq-general-policy-questions)